# Is County-Level Aggregation Sufficient To Anonymize?

Tags: aggregation, ecology

Is county-level aggregation sufficient to anonymize the data such as that found in the US Census or GSS?

Comment: Can you define the columns/attributes  in your dataset before and after the aggregation?

Comment: Not at present.  This is for a cross disciplinary social science contest so it must be very wide ranging.

Comment: If you could provide an example it would be easy to answer. Anyway, aggregating in general cannot be enough. Take a look for instance to the concept of k-anonymity, it may help you.

Comment: It depends. Not always. It depends on how your groups are defined. People who are relatively rare might be identifiable in a county.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer precisely without a more detailed information. However, in general aggregating might not be enough. Have a look to the concept of [k-anonymity](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjSnZX7xt7UAhXRfFAKHbmlDzcQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fmrzarema%2F20k-ANONYMITYAMODELFORPROTECTINGPRIV.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGNK5h-Hf2fVYGAdQiqDXCoDN5fCg&cad=rja) (also l-diversity and t-consistency). As David Smith says people with uncommon quasi-identifiers (combination of data such as gender,age,profession), can be easiliy disclosed.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, not in general.

As a simple example, suppose you had access to the number of hospital visits broken out by income ranges released at the county level.

If the dataset revealed that 1 person from the $1,000,000+ income bracket visited the hospital, and only 1 person in the county had an income that was greater than that amount, then you have effectively revealed the identity of that patient. This problem is demonstrated in the table below using Loving County, TX (total population of 113) as an example.

```
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| County                   | Loving County, TX |
| Population $0k-1M Income | 112               |
| Visits $0k-1M Income     | 12                |
| Population $1M+ Income   | 1                 |
| Visits $1M+ Income       | 1                 |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

Specific knowledge of the data and statistical contemplation must be taken into account to ensure aggregated data is sufficiently anonymized.